# python json load not able parse date format

Tags: python, json

i am trying to read json file with json load it throws error with date field (22-04-2000).for other fields which are strings i dont see any issue.seems there is parse issue with date format can someone help me on this?.i have tried placing that in String format too but still no luck.

Comment: Please can you share the JSON and the error

Comment: `22-04-2000` is not a valid JSON value, putting that within a string `"22-04-2000"` should have fixed that particular issue. If you show us your JSON, we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard JSON representation of dates.
dates are stored in json in string format.

to push a **date** value to json object, first convert it to **string**.

```
var date = (new Date()).toString();
jsondata.push({"date":  date});
```

to get **date** value back from json get the element then use

```
var date = new Date(jsondata.date);
```